# SQL Server LocalDB deployment on IIS with Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, windows-installer

I'm trying to use a LocalDB as an alternative database for a Asp.net 4.6 Website I'm developing.  The website will be installed using an install program on a customers web server.

Will the install program need to install SQL Server LocalDB or is it enough to simply copy the `.mdf` file during installtion and attach to that file in the SQL Server connection string?

Comment: I haven't seen any mention of LocalDB being for developers only.  Just that it is targered to developers.  You are correct though that it seems to need a SQL Server Express installation.  Thanks.

Comment: @marc_s Yes, that's what I said.  "Targeted to developers." which is not the same as "designed for development only."

Comment: I installed SQL Server Express in my IIS server machine. But still can't make it work. What should I do?